# Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::addAttributeToSort error in Magento

Tags: magento

The featured section was working fine until yesterday, but started getting error. We have not made any changes. I searched the forum for similar issue but couldn’t find any. May I know what is causing the issue.

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::addAttributeToSort(Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => ASC
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/username/public_html/app/design/frontend/usernamey/default_v2/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(149): Varien_Object->__call('addAttributeToS...', Array)
#1 /home/username/public_html/app/design/frontend/usernamey/default_v2/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(149): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
#2 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/username/...')
#3 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/machin...')
#4 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 /home/username/public_html/app/design/frontend/usernamey/default_v2/template/page/3columns.phtml(72): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/username/...')
#12 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/machin...')
#13 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#19 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#20 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/username/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/username/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from `template/catalog/category/view.phtml` around line 149? most probably you are trying to list something (categories or products) but you call `addAttributeToSort` on the current category instead of a collection.

Comment: @Marius I have pasted the code of `template/catalog/category/view.phtml` at [link](http://pastie.org/8571234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem, like I suspected:

```
$cat_ = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($id_cat)->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
$productD = $cat_->getProductCollection();
```

I think this should be:

```
$cat_ = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($id_cat);
$productD = $cat_->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```